# Defining percentual height for div (CSS) with Google Maps element

Tags: html, css, google-maps, height, percentage

I'm trying to create a "Contact" section for my website, where I'd have text on the left side and a Google Maps element on the right side to show our location. At the moment I have managed to get the divs next to each other, but the problem is that I can't seem to get the map's height to match the div next to it. I have looked at other questions and examples, and the most popular answer seems to be "add a wrapper and define its height and width to 100% and then define the div's height to 100%, too", but this hasn't worked for me. I don't want to define a fixed px height for the map, since then it won't adapt to the width of the window in a responsive way.

At the moment I have:

HTML

```
<!-- CONTACT SECTION -->
  <div class="third" id="contacts">

    <div class="starter-template">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2><br>
      <div class="basic-container">
        <div class="contact">
          <p class="lead">Location</p>
          <p>The student team spaces can be found at Urban Mill, located between Startup Sauna and Aalto Design Factory at the Aalto University campus in Otaniemi, Espoo (Street Address: Betonimiehenkuja 3, Espoo, Finland). Most of the lectures will also be held at Urban Mill. The accommodation of the students is at Forenom Hostel (Street Address: Kivimiehentie 2, Espoo), which is only a 5-minute walk away from Urban Mill.<br><br></p>
          <p class="lead">Get in Touch</p>
          startupsummerprogram@outlook.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
          <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7936.021807966812!2d24.832175000000017!3d60.18064199999999!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x468df58d0b88505f%3A0xaacf6d4afeea4ebb!2sUrban+Mill!5e0!3m2!1sfi!2sfi!4v1434351601478" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

And CSS:

```
.third {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.basic-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.contact {
  width: 49%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2%;
}

.contact p.lead {
  text-align: left;
}

#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The starter-template seen in the HTML code is there because of a starter Bootstrap template I'm using. I don't believe it affects this height issue, though :)

The code I have creates this:

[image]

And what I'd like to have is this (I achieved this demo by adding a fixed px value for the map's height):

[image]

There must be a simple way to handle this, but for some reason my brain doesn't want to cooperate with me on this. All help is very much appreciated :)

Joanna

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Hope it helps!

Working code link: https://jsfiddle.net/jxfw0r16/8/

Basically I've changed the .contact and #map of your css.

```
<div class="starter-template">
  <h2>Contact Us</h2><br>
  <div class="basic-container">
    <div class="contact">
      <p class="lead">Location</p>
      <p>The student team spaces can be found at Urban Mill, located between Startup Sauna and Aalto Design Factory at the Aalto University campus in Otaniemi, Espoo (Street Address: Betonimiehenkuja 3, Espoo, Finland). Most of the lectures will also be held at Urban Mill. The accommodation of the students is at Forenom Hostel (Street Address: Kivimiehentie 2, Espoo), which is only a 5-minute walk away from Urban Mill.<br><br></p>
      <p class="lead">Get in Touch</p>
      startupsummerprogram@outlook.com</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
      <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7936.021807966812!2d24.832175000000017!3d60.18064199999999!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x468df58d0b88505f%3A0xaacf6d4afeea4ebb!2sUrban+Mill!5e0!3m2!1sfi!2sfi!4v1434351601478" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.third {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.basic-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.contact {
  position: relative;
  width: 49%;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 60%;
}

.contact p.lead {
  text-align: left;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: #map and .contact where changed in the css, they needed to have certain position each one and other minor fixes.

Comment: what are the position changes and other minor fixes and how did each of them contribute to answering the question?

Comment: The .contact div is given a zero height and a percentage bottom padding, then the padding-bottom is the percentage of the container width for aspect ratio reasons, also the div container must be relative and the iframe absolute so its shown inside at 0 from its height.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, @user3272243.
This works a bit better than my code, but the problem is that the height really only looks good when the window width is about 670. When the window width grows to about 1200, the height of the map is a lot bigger than the height of the contact div next to it, like this: https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3704/18825732342_70fe7842c0_k.jpg
Do you know how it could be fixed so that it looks symmetrical to the left contact div at all window widths? :)

Comment: @jonsbaa Sorry for the late reply, check this out, i think it will solve your problem with the height: https://jsfiddle.net/jxfw0r16/13/ Basically i've changed the iframe class of contact to contact2 and got rid of the     height: 0%; Also I've changed the height on your basic-container so you can see that it works properly.

Comment: @user3272243 thanks again for trying to help, but I'm not sure if we're talking about the same problem right now. In your solution, the height of the map still changes when you broaden the window. I would like the map and the contact section to be of equal heights regardless of the window width, as shown in the original question. Now, when you broaden the window of that jsfiddle sample, the height of the map visibly changes. When the window is narrow, the map's height gets smaller and smaller compared to the text section, and when the window is broad, the map's height gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: Hummm, lemme check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Check this link. https://jsfiddle.net/c287hgpc/

```
      <div class="third" id="contacts">
        <div class="starter-template">
          <h2>Contact Us</h2><br>
          <div class="basic-container">
            <div class="contact">
              <p class="lead">Location</p>
              <p>The student team spaces can be found at Urban Mill, located between Startup Sauna and Aalto Design Factory at the Aalto University campus in Otaniemi, Espoo (Street Address: Betonimiehenkuja 3, Espoo, Finland). Most of the lectures will also be held at Urban Mill. The accommodation of the students is at Forenom Hostel (Street Address: Kivimiehentie 2, Espoo), which is only a 5-minute walk away from Urban Mill.<br><br></p>
              <p class="lead">Get in Touch</p>
              <p>+358465943409<br>
              startupsummerprogram@outlook.com</p>
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
              <iframe id="map" 
              src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d7936.021807966812!2d24.832175000000017!3d60.18064199999999!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x468df58d0b88505f%3A0xaacf6d4afeea4ebb!2sUrban+Mill!5e0!3m2!1sfi!2sfi!4v1434351601478" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
```

css codes

```
    .third {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.basic-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 100%;
}

.contact {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 2%;
  width: 46%;
}

.contact p.lead {
  text-align: left;
}
.starter-template h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: The text and iframe is totally out  .third div which is the wrapper, not to mention that the height of the map is still the same to the example given above.

Comment: As @user3272243 said, this doesn't really work. The height of the map still has the same problem as before and the text and map are out of their original places.